# Pulling an image halfway outside of its <div>

Tags: html, css

I've seen some news websites (can't seem to find a link now though) that pull images **50% outside** of the text column when the @media is somewhere around (min-width: 1200px).

The only way I know how to pull an image outside of a  with a max width is by using

```
position:absolute;
left: -100px;
```

However, text cannot wrap around this (the image overlays on top of text) and it also doesn't pull the image exactly 50%. Can this be done with css/html with the image inside of a parent ?

Comment: You can give it a negative margin-left. Do you mean 50% of the image width or 50% of the column width?

Answer (score 3):

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid red; width: 100%">
  <img src="http://smalldata.io/startup/common-files/icons/sdl_logo.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Di mo na sir kailaingan ang html, head, body kapag gumagamit ka ng SO code snippet at yung indentation mo for good practice na din ;)

Comment: @LaraBelle Thanks for the tip :D. Barely uses the code snippet

Comment: Welcome. I nose my bleed. Always keep your hands dirty. ;)

Comment: @LaraBelle My nose is blooding here hahaha, thanks again. Cheers :D